# Gridview paging not working with datatable(dt)

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, paging

Can anyone help me in figuring out the problem with gridView Paging. I have to use datatable as data source. But unable to bind it again.

```
protected void CommGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    commGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    commGridView.DataSource = GetData(blist,elist,clist); // this function return a datatabe(dt)
    commGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: here you need to use PagedDataSource to do pagination or else you need to call store procedure to get records by page size and page number

Comment: @KevinShah Can you elaborate using some example ..  because i have tired with different ways but its not working ..

Comment: Your code looks correct, but are you sure those three variables are what you expect them to be. Sorting does a PostBack and might reset those values if you declared them outside a Method. Try with fixed values first.

Comment: @VDWWD i have tried this with a single value but its not working .. :(

Comment: Need to see your page load code. What's not working? Unable to bind means ? Are you able to debug & see any issues?